# Spring Security expressions for permission code and name

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, jwt, spring-security-oauth2

In my Spring Security project I have a following method secured with `@PreAuthorize` annotation:

```
@PreAuthorize("hasAnyAuthority('PERMISSION_UPDATE_OWN_DECISION', 'PERMISSION_UPDATE_ANY_DECISION')")
@RequestMapping(value = "/{decisionId}/update", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public DecisionResponse updateDecision(@PathVariable @NotNull @DecimalMin("0") Long decisionId, @Valid @RequestBody UpdateDecisionRequest decisionRequest) {
    ....
}
```

I also use Spring OAuth2 with JWT tokens and store all authorities inside of this token. Now, I use pretty long permission names, for example `PERMISSION_UPDATE_OWN_DECISION` and would like to replace them in order to significantly decrease JWT token size(authorities section).

[image]

One of the ideas is to introduce permission codes, something like:

```
1, PERMISSION_UPDATE_OWN_DECISION
2, PERMISSION_UPDATE_ANY_DECISION
```

where `1` is a permission code and `PERMISSION_UPDATE_OWN_DECISION` is a permission name.

But I don't want to use these codes directly because it will reduce the readability of my code, for example:

```
@PreAuthorize("hasAnyAuthority('1', '2')")
```

instead of this I'd like to use something that will allow me to retrieve this codes based on the real permission names, for example:

```
@PreAuthorize("hasAnyAuthority(getCode('PERMISSION_UPDATE_OWN_DECISION')), getCode('PERMISSION_UPDATE_ANY_DECISION'))")
```

How to correctly implement this with Spring Security and Spring Security Expressions ? May be there is some pre-built approach in order to achieve this ?

Answer (score 1):

First of all you need to subclass `MethodSecurityExpressionRoot` and create a Custom Class with your logic.

```
public class CustomMethodSecurityExpressionRoot extends MethodSecurityExpressionRoot {
    public boolean hasAnyAuthorityWithCodes(String... codes) {
         String[] ids = // Your custom Logic to get Ids from Code

         return hasAnyAuthority(ids);
    }

}
```

And then Subclass `DefaultMethodSecurityExpressionHandler` and override `createEvaluationContext` method of it.

```
@Override
public EvaluationContext createEvaluationContext(Authentication auth, MethodInvocation mi) {
    MethodSecurityEvaluationContext ctx = new MethodSecurityEvaluationContext(auth, mi, parameterNameDiscoverer);
    MethodSecurityExpressionRoot root = new CustomMethodSecurityExpressionRoot(auth);
    root.setTrustResolver(trustResolver);
    root.setPermissionEvaluator(permissionEvaluator);
    root.setRoleHierarchy(roleHierarchy);
    ctx.setRootObject(root);

    return ctx;
}
```

And Finally you can make use of this custom `DefaultMethodSecurityExpressionHandler` in your configuration

```
<global-method-security>
  <expression-handler ref="customMethodSecurityExpressionHandler"/>
</global-method-security>
```

And use

```
@PreAuthorize("hasAnyAuthorityWithCodes('PERMISSION_UPDATE_OWN_DECISION','PERMISSION_UPDATE_ANY_DECISION')")
```

**UPDATE**

Subclass `DefaultMethodSecurityExpressionHandler` and override `createSecurityExpressionRoot` method

```
    protected MethodSecurityExpressionOperations createSecurityExpressionRoot(
        Authentication authentication, MethodInvocation invocation) {
        MethodSecurityExpressionRoot root = new CustomMethodSecurityExpressionRoot(
                authentication);
        root.setThis(invocation.getThis());
        root.setTrustResolver(trustResolver);
        root.setPermissionEvaluator(permissionEvaluator);
        root.setRoleHierarchy(roleHierarchy);
        root.setDefaultRolePrefix(defauleRolePrefix);

        return root;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Right now I have a following error: 
Cannot override the final method createEvaluationContext from AbstractSecurityExpressionHandler<MethodInvocation> CustomMethodSecurityExpressionHandler.java  This is Spring Security Core 4.0.3.RELEASE

Comment: now getTrustResolver() and getDefaultRolePrefix() methods are both undefined in my CustomMethodSecurityExpressionHandler

Comment: Do you have any ideas how to adjust it ? Thanks

Comment: See Update to fix.

Comment: Thanks but maybe I'm doing something wrong - I can't access trustResolver,  permissionEvaluator and roleHierarchy because they are private and can't be accessed from my CustomMethodSecurityExpressionHandler

Comment: I was wrong - I'm using Spring Security Core 4.1.3.RELEASE

Comment: How do you access these private members in subclass ?

Comment: Is any way to do this under Spring Security Core 4.1.3.RELEASE ?